# How to get decimal from POW()

Tags: mysql, decimal, exponential

I am running a command similar to this in mysql 5.6:

```
SELECT pow(2, 87) FROM `table`
```

And the results are always shown in scientific notation, and when trying to CAST it to a decimal I am losing all the precision.  Is there a way to simply output the full decimal value of this equation?

Comment: what do you expect? 2^87 vastly exceeds 2^64 which is the max integer mysql can handle. "I'm pouring 500 gallons into this little teacup. why is it overflowing?"

Comment: You do realize that not everyone knows the limit to what mysql can do right?  Thanks for the sarcasm.